# How to add DAO recordset as rows in a datasheet subform

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have the following code to move product information from a sales quote to a lease qualification form. The products go to a subform which is in datasheet view, however, each row in the recordset just updates the first row of the subform.

```
sql = "SELECT ProdID, ProdQty, ProdPrice FROM ProductsQuoted WHERE quoteID = " & quoteeID
  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql)

  If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
     rs.MoveFirst
     Do Until rs.EOF
        [Forms]![Qualification]![QualificationDetails]![Item] = rs.Fields("ProdID").Value
        [Forms]![Qualification]![QualificationDetails]![Qty] = rs.Fields("ProdQty").Value
        [Forms]![Qualification]![QualificationDetails]![Price] = rs.Fields("ProdPrice").Value
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
  End If
```

How can I have each record in the dataset update a new row on the subform?

Comment: Instead of using `Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql)`, why don't you use `Set rs = db.OpenRecordset()`?

Comment: Yes, that is a good thought. I could do that. I've made that change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I was able to use DoCmd.GoToRecord,, acNewRec and meet my need.

```
sql = "SELECT ProdID, ProdQty, ProdPrice FROM ProductsQuoted WHERE quoteID = " & quoteeID
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sql)

       If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
        rs.MoveFirst
        Do Until rs.EOF
            Debug.Print rs.Fields("ProdID") & ", " & rs.Fields("ProdQty") & ", " & rs.Fields("ProdPrice")
            QualificationDetails.SetFocus
            QualificationDetails!Item.SetFocus
            DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
            [Forms]![Qualification]![QualificationDetails]![Item] = rs.Fields("ProdID").Value
            [Forms]![Qualification]![QualificationDetails]![Qty] = rs.Fields("ProdQty").Value
            [Forms]![Qualification]![QualificationDetails]![Price] = rs.Fields("ProdPrice").Value
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
```